# TypeError: as_view() - Django

Tags: python, django, web-services, django-rest-framework, geodjango

I got an error.

And i have no ideia how to fix it, take a look, this is the error:

```
TypeError: as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This as you can see is the code of my "model.py" page.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models


class RoadsLines(models.Model):
    gid = models.IntegerField()
    geom = models.MultiLineStringField()

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return '%s %s' % (self.gid, self.geom)
```

This as you can see is the code of my "views.py" page.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics
from world.models import RoadsLines
from world.serializers import RoadsLinesSerializer


class ListCreateRoadsLines(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = RoadsLines.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RoadsLinesSerializer
```

This as you can see is the code of my "urls.py" page.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from world import views

# Routers provide an easy way of automatically determining the URL conf.
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'Roads', views.ListCreateRoadsLines)

# Wire up our API using automatic URL routing.
# Additionally, we include login URLs for the browsable API.
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What URL are you trying to access?

Comment: try using `views.ListCreateRoadsLines()` instead of `views.ListCreateRoadsLines`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListCreateRoadsLines` is a view, not a viewset. You should include it in your url patterns, instead of trying to register it:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^Roads$', views.ListCreateRoadsLines.as_view()),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include('rest_framework.urls', 
    namespace='rest_framework'))
]
```